# Empty NSWindow sheet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I'm working on an OSX application with basically 2 differents windows : a main one and another window displayed as a sheet on top of the other one It looks like this : http://cl.ly/0c0l0d0q3i2y1Y3y2b0b)

I'm trying to open it using the following code :

```
BookWindow *bookWindow = [[BookWindow alloc] init];
[NSApp beginSheet:installWindow modalForWindow:window modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
```

It show up as wanted, but it's empty...
Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you uncheck the "Visible At Launch" attribute for installWindow's window element in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes. If I don't it shows and looks like as expected, it's when I open it via code, then it's empty .